# Input number value minus second input number value returns NaN

Tags: jquery, html

when I write for example 50 into `.res`input and 25 to second input `.res2` and click equal it MUST minus but alert returns Not a Number

```
<div class="wind">
     <input class="res" value=" " maxlength="24">
     <input class="res2" value=" " maxlength="24">
     <button class="equal">=</button>
<div class="numbers">
```

```
$(".one,.two,.three,.four,.five,.six,.seven,.eight,.nine,.zero,.dot").on('mousedown',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if($('.res').is(":focus")){
        firstNumber = $('.res').val(Number(($('.res').val()) + $(this).val()));
} else {
    secondNumber = $('.res2').val(Number(($('.res2').val()) + $(this).val()));
    }
})
$('.equal').click(function(){
    alert(firstNumber-secondNumber);
})
```

Comment: Your first click handler won't work, as `$('.res').is(':focus')` will never be true as you had to have clicked one of the other elements to fire the event. I'm not sure exactly how you're expecting the logic to work.

Answer (score 2):

The `firstNumber` and `secondNumber` variables are defined in the first click handler, out of scope of the `.equal` click handler. You need to instead retrieve the values from the DOM when that event occurs, like this:

```js
$('.equal').click(function() {
  var firstNumber = parseInt($('.res').val(), 10);
  var secondNumber = parseInt($('.res2').val(), 10);
  console.log(firstNumber - secondNumber);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wind">
  <input class="res" value="50" maxlength="24">
  <input class="res2" value="25" maxlength="24">
  <button class="equal">=</button>
  <div class="numbers"></div>
</div>
```